# Команда Break в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

в javaScript команда break meltka; работает только на счётчиках?
Вставляю в IF, скрипт перестаёт интерпретировать дальнейшие команды.
DreamWeiver сразу предупреждает об ошибке.
Как правильно её применять?
Вставляю чужой код с ним, вроде работает.
В моей функции - нет

---

Всё!   [Нашёл хорошую статью](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/3fhdxafb(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: break - это для циклов и switch'ей... из if'а надо выходить штатно.

Comment: [Здесь — всё](http://javascript.ru/break).

Comment: Всё!
[Нашёл хорошую статью](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/3fhdxafb(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ из комментариев:

break не работает для оператора if.
[Статья по теме](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3fhdxafb(v=vs.94).aspx)